# How do I use mouseListener to add a new Image in Slick2d

Tags: java, image, slick2d

I want to make the code so that when I click somewhere in the container, I create a new image with the coordinates of mouseX and Y of where I clicked.

I tried to do this, but I'm not sure how I will draw a new image, without the old image getting the same coordinates as the new one, and I'm not sure if I'm even creating different images right now, or if it's just the same image I'm changing the coordinates of whenever I click.

I was thinking about creating an array list of images, and then whenever I click somewhere, it adds a new image to the list, and then the render just keeps rendering the entire list, but here I'm not sure how to tell the render where each image was clicked (the coordinates).

Here's what I have so far, I'd really appreciate if someone could help me. Let me know if there's something you need me to clarify :)

```
    package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class SimpleSlickGame extends BasicGame
{

    public String mouseCoords;
    public String testClick ="Nothing clicked";
    public int mouseX;
    public int mouseY;

    public SimpleSlickGame(String gamename)
    {
        super(gamename);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
        mouseCoords = "";
    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer gc, int i) throws SlickException {
        int mouseX = Mouse.getX();
        int mouseY = Mouse.getY();

        mouseCoords = "Mouse X: "+ mouseX + " Mouse Y: "+ mouseY;               

    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException
    {
        g.drawString(mouseCoords, 250, 200);
        g.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
        g.drawString(testClick, 200, 400);

        g.drawImage(new Image("images/house.png"), mouseX, mouseY);

    }

    public void mousePressed(int button, int x, int y){
        mouseX = x;
        mouseY = y;

        if (button == 0){
            if((x> 100 && x<200) && (y > 100 && y < 200)){
                testClick = "inside box";
            }
            else{
                testClick = "outside box";

            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AppGameContainer appgc;
            appgc = new AppGameContainer(new SimpleSlickGame("Simple Slick Game"));
            appgc.setDisplayMode(600, 600, false);
            appgc.start();
        }
        catch (SlickException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleSlickGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did some reading of documents and googling and found a solution :P, although I'm not sure if it's the most optimal way of doing this (would really like some critique!!)

Here's what I did:

The main class:

```
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class SimpleSlickGame extends BasicGame
{

    public String mouseCoords;
    public String testClick ="Nothing clicked";
    public int mouseX;
    public int mouseY;
    private House[] house = new House[10];
    public List<House> houses = new ArrayList<House>();
    public House houseTest, houseTest2, houseTest3;

    public SimpleSlickGame(String gamename)
    {
        super(gamename);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
        mouseCoords = "";

    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer gc, int i) throws SlickException {
        int mouseX = Mouse.getX();
        int mouseY = Mouse.getY();

        mouseCoords = "Mouse X: "+ mouseX + " Mouse Y: "+ mouseY;               

    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException
    {
        g.drawString(mouseCoords, 250, 200);
        g.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
        g.drawString(testClick, 200, 400);


        for(int i = 0; i<houses.size();i++){
            if(houses.get(i) != null){
            houses.get(i).render(gc, g);
            }
        }


    }

    public void mousePressed(int button, int x, int y){
        mouseX = x;
        mouseY = y;

        if (button == 0){
            if((x> 100 && x<200) && (y > 100 && y < 200)){
                testClick = "inside box";
                houses.add(new House(mouseX,mouseY));

            }
            else{
                testClick = "outside box";

            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AppGameContainer appgc;
            appgc = new AppGameContainer(new SimpleSlickGame("Simple Slick Game"));
            appgc.setDisplayMode(600, 600, false);
            appgc.start();
        }
        catch (SlickException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleSlickGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

House class:

```
package example;

import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class House {

    int x;
    int y;
    int width = 20;
    int height = 20;


    House(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException
    {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems quite good. Just be aware of several things: 1) in the question you create a `new Image` on every cycle, you should declare your image in the class then just draw it in render (in general: never use `new` in render or update). 2) ATM  you're only drawing white shape, but when you'll draw images care about your image creation too, declare it once and then use it several time.